# Convert function arguments to lists

Tags: python

I have a function with a definite set of arguments, but that during development the amount of arguments it recieves could change.
Each argument can either be a string, or a list. I want to someway loop trough the arguments of the function, and if they are a string, convert them to a list with that single element.

I tried using `locals()` to be able to loop trough the arguments, but I don't know how to modify the value during the iteration, so I guess that's not the correct approach:

```
def function(a, b, c, d):
    for key in locals():
        if type(key) == str:
            # ??? key = list(locals[key])

    # ... more code over here, assuming that a,b,c,d are lists
```

What's the correct way to acomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: use *args or **kwargs

Comment: I'd rather not use *args because the arguments I recieve in the function are explicit. I could easily do `if type(a)==str: a = list(a)' for each argument, but if the signature of the function changes during development, I want this behaviour to adapt dinamically.

Comment: You can't "modify the value during iteration" within a function anyway as assignment to the locals dict doesn't update the locals...

Comment: Exactly, I don't know which other way I can dinamically transform every str recieved to a list, so I can assume all the variables are lists from there on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isinstance(key, str)` to check if a variable is a str or not

```
def function(a, b, c, d):
    l= locals()
    for i in l:
        key = l[i]
        if isinstance(key, str):
            l[i] = [l[i]]
    l = l.values()
    print (l)
function('one', 'two', ['bla','bla'], ['ble'])
```

If you want list, then you need to have a line

```
 l = l.values()
```

This will be

```
[['a'], ['c'], ['b'], ['d']]
```

**EDIT**: As you have suggested, the correct program is

```
def function(a, b, c, d):
    l= locals()
    dirty= False
    for i in l:
        key = l[i]
        if isinstance(key, str):
            l[i] = [l[i]]
            dirty= True
    if dirty:
        function(**l)
    else:
        print a, b, c, d
    print (l)

function('one', 'two', ['bla','bla'], ['ble'])
```

This will output

```
['one'], ['bla', 'bla'], ['two'], ['ble']
```

Comment: What I want is to actually do `a,b,c,d=l` where the print is, so I can code the rest of the function assuming that all four values are lists, but without explicitly naming `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in that line.

Comment: @Zamaroht So you want to access variables as a list?

Comment: I want that if, for example, I call the function with `function('one', 'two', ['bla','bla'], ['ble'])`, after executing some code I can assume during the rest of the function that the values are `['one']`, `['two']`, `['bla','bla']` and `['ble']` for a, b, c and d respectively.

Comment: What I actually wanted is to set the parameters of a,b,c,d to the values in l.
You gave me the idea to make it work with some recursion and a dirty flag, this is the code that works, feel free to include it in the answer:

`def function(a, b, c, d):
    l= locals()
    dirty=False
    for i in l:
        key = l[i]
        if isinstance(key, str):
            l[i] = [l[i]]
            dirty=True
    if dirty:
     function(**l)
    else:
     print a, b, c, d

function('bla', ['ble'], 'me', ['gsa','gs'])`

Thanks!

Comment: @Zamaroht Thanks for the edit, do accept the answer if you fell it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Use [`*args` or `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs):

```
def use_args(*args):
    # covert strings to `list` containing them
    new_args = map(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, str) else x, args)
    return new_args
print use_args([1, 2], "3")
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], ['3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(*args):

    arg_list = list(args)
    for i in range(len(arg_list)):
        if type(arg_list[i]) == str:
            #Do the stuff
        elif type(arg_list[i]) == list:
            #Do the stuff
        else:
            #Do the stuff

function ('a','b', ['c', 'd', 'e'])
```